# Change position (order) of alphabetical and numbers in a string

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

I have a valid css class name like `obj2`
I want to use the parseInt() function which gives me: `NaN`
Now I want to change the position of the letters and numbers that I get: `2obj`

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: Why do you want to use parseInt on a string that contains alfabetic characters?

Comment: I use that method to get rid of the letters so I only get the Number. Which would be the Integer "2" in this example.

Comment: You only want the number portion from the string? E.g. `420` from the string `inner-wrap-420px`?

Comment: @SalmanA That's right. I only want the number. And it should be a pure Integer in the end.

Comment: @Tom: See my revised answer in a few minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Classes can't start with a number.

But you can in JS:

```
var className = "obj2";
var number = className.replace("obj", "");
```

Now: `number is String("2")` and `parseFloat(number) is Number(2)`

Answer (score 0):

If the number is always the last character of always after 3 precending alfabetic characters, you can try to accomplish this with methods like [substr](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substr.asp). If the text always contains a fixed string like "obj", you can also remove that from the string and use the remainder for whatever purpose you have with the number.

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions and matching groups are probably the way forward to get the result you want.

First declare the regular expresion to match digits after alphabetical characters, then apply it to the input string, finally reassemble.

```
var regex = /([a-zA-Z]*)(\d+)/;
var matches = regex.exec("obj2");
var numeric = matches[2];
var myInt = parseInt(numeric);
var alpha = matches[1];
var newFormat = numeric+aplha;
```

However you won'e be allowed that as a css class as it starts with a number.

For more information on regular expresions in javascript: http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html